# Bootstrap 4 columns overflowing instead of resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've read 5-6 question / answers but can't find what I'm looking for _ 
Bootstrap 4 columns aren't behaving the way I expect them to. Below about 600px device width the edge overflows instead of continuing to reduce in size

[at 618px the columns are still reducing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tl12.png)

[at 538px the columns are overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6VwB.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
           <div class="outerDivBorder" id="photoBox">
               <div style="height: 10em;"></div> 
           </div><!-- /#photoBox -->
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
            <div class="outerDivBorder" id="dataBox">
                <div style="height: 10em;"></div> 
            </div><!-- /#dataBox -->
       </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS:

```
.outerDivBorder {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #454343;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance offered on this : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `margin: 1rem;` on `.outerDivBorder`, and that margin pushes content out on small screens. Use padding on `col`s instead - it can be done by using utility class for padding, `py-3` in this case:

```css
.outerDivBorder {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #454343;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 py-3">
           <div class="outerDivBorder" id="photoBox">
               <div style="height: 10em;"></div> 
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 py-3">
            <div class="outerDivBorder" id="dataBox"> 
                <div style="height: 10em;"></div> 
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. On mine it was happening because of

```css
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Bootstrap already reset that to `border-box` and the col's and row's behave according to that.